# i just want some $row data some only one time not show all data because all same and no need .. i am working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i just want some $row data show only one time not show all the time. Because all data is in one tuple is same. And no need to show again again .

Is This code is fine but not working ? I  show all the data repeat same why ? i  am working in codeigniter .

code is here:

```
 foreach ($data as $row)                    
     $i=0;                              
     if ($i==0){                                  
     echo $row->vehicle_number;}
     $i=1;
```

Comment: What output do you expect, what output are you actually getting? Have you stepped through the code with a debugger?

Comment: pls use `$db->get()->row()` to return only one row of data

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50812159/edit) your question and provide more information (as requested by other people). As it is now, it is quite hard to understand and reproduce your problem. See: [How to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Note : you should return only one row of data with either with `$db->get()->row()` or `$db->get()->first_row(`); or `$db->get()->last_row()` so that there is no need to loop through the data;

Do something like this :

```
foreach ($data as $key => $row) 
{   
   if ($key == 0 )
   { 
     $data['vehicle_number'] = $row->vehicle_number;
     $data['route_name'] = $row->route_name;
     $data['route_time'] = $row->route_time;
     $data['status'] = $row->status;
   }
   $data[$key]['id '] = $row->id ;
   $data[$key]['vehicle_id'] = $row->vehicle_id;
   $data[$key]['point'] = $row->point;
   $data[$key]['time'] = $row->time;        
}
print_r($data);
```

Comment: i want that some of this fields show only one time like  "vehicle_number"  "route_name" "route_time" "status"  and show all record regarding  this fields " time" "point" ..

Comment: how can it possible without seeing your data structure? provide your $data

Comment: see my updated answer hope this will solve your problem , put your field in if condition which u want to set one time , remaining will be in outside if condition

Comment: have you checked my answer is it helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `$db->get()->row_array()` in your model and this will return a single row from the database.

Comment: i have a these fields   
id
vehicle_id
vehicle_number
point
status
time
route_name
route_time